# Lightroom crashed during export; a few damaged photos. What are my options?

Tags: lightroom

Lightroom CC crashed on me the other day, leaving four damaged photos. Luckily I have the exported photos fine but I would like to recover my working copies if possible.

I backup every time it prompts me too, but I'm still learning Lightroom.

**What can I do?**

They show up in `Develop` with the message:

> "The file appears to be unsupported or damaged"

Comment: Can you open those photos with any other graphic viewer?

Comment: The backup is only the catalog. You're still on the hook for backing up your masters.

Comment: Do you still have the master photos? lightroom is non-destructive editing tool. the exports may be damaged but the master raw should be untouched.

Answer (score 1):

The original photos should be unharmed. You can remove the damaged photos from the catalog and add them again. Only problem is, you will lose all modifications you did to them.